# Assigning multiple values to an environment at once

Tags: r, environment, r-s3

Given an environment `x`, a convenient shorthand for `assign(x, value, envir = e)` is to write `e[[x]] <- value`. Currently, there is not an analog to the subset operator for assigning multiple objects at once:

```
> e = new.env(parent = emptyenv())
> e[["a"]] <- 1
> ls(e)
[1] "a"
> e[c("b", "c")] <- c(1,2)
Error in e[c("b", "c")] <- c(1, 2) : 
  object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

I was hoping to write one using the built in S3 functionality for `[<-`. The first oddity I noticed was that both `[[<-` and `[<-` are primitive functions despite imitating S3 functions:

```
> methods("[<-")
[1] [<-.data.frame  [<-.Date        [<-.environment [<-.factor      [<-.POSIXct     [<-.POSIXlt     [<-.raster*     [<-.ts*
```

Normally, S3 functions have the format where the body is just a call to `UseMethod`. For example:

```
> summary
function (object, ...) 
UseMethod("summary")
<bytecode: 0x1a7c3a8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

In addition to the assignment operators being primitive, there is no S3 method for `[[<-` for class `environment`:

```
> methods(class = environment)
[1] as.list.environment
```

So the original assignment using `[[<-` must be done using the default, if there is such a default for a primitive function. Despite this, I implemented an S3 function for `[<-.environment`:

```
> `[<-.environment` = function(x, names, values) {
mapply(function(name, value) { x[[name]] <- value }, names, values) }
```

This appears to behave as if it were correctly implemented for the following:

```
> methods(class = environment)
[1] [<-.environment     as.list.environment
> methods(`[<-`)
[1] [<-.data.frame  [<-.Date        [<-.environment [<-.factor      [<-.POSIXct     [<-.POSIXlt     [<-.raster*     [<-.ts*
```

However, it runs into the same error:

```
> e = new.env(parent = emptyenv())
> e[c("b", "c")] <- c(1,2)
Error in e[c("b", "c")] <- c(1, 2) : 
  object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

Could someone explain both the inconsistency with the S3 methods for `[<-` and `[[<-`, as well how to correctly implement subset assignment for environments?

Comment: `list2env` may be of ues here.

Comment: Also this works but may not be the best approach: `lapply(1:2, function(i) assign(c("b", "c")[i], c(1,2)[i], envir=e))`

Comment: Of related interest: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/list-assignment-syntax-td4520641.html from 2012, there was another from '08 along similar lines and yet another even earlier ('04) as an implementation attempt... You are two years early on the request.

Comment: My main concern was how to overwrite the subset assignment operator `[<-` and not the body of that function. My secondary interest was in how that operator and `[[<-` are actually performed in the back-end, as they appear to use S3 functionality on the surface but are actually primitive functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start, modified from `?list2env`

```
L <- list(a = 1, b = 2:4, p = pi, ff = gl(3, 4, labels = LETTERS[1:3]))
e <- list2env(L)
addToEnv <- function(e, names, values) {
    l1 <- sapply(values, list)
    names(l1) <- names
    el1 <- mget(ls(e), envir=e)
    al1 <- as.list(c(el1, l1))
    return(list2env(al1))
    }
e2 <- addToEnv(e, names=letters[7:8], values=letters[9:10])
mget(ls(e2), envir=e2)
```

giving:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2 3 4

$ff
 [1] A A A A B B B B C C C C
Levels: A B C

$g
[1] "i"

$h
[1] "j"

$p
[1] 3.141593
```

I admit this isn't v. efficient, but should work for small sized environments.